# How to integrate the Cucumber-Selenium scripts with Jmeter for the performance testing

Tags: jmeter, cucumber

Just want to understand how can we integrated our selenium scripts using cucumber can be integrated in Jmeter?

or any other way we can add any Jmeter plugin to our selenium scripts or some extra configuration is required, so while running automation scripts the Jmeter report is also generated.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber has [many faces](https://cucumber.io/docs) so you need to be more specific regarding the programming language you used for your tests.

For example if it is Java and [JUnit](http://junit.org/) - you can easily integrate your tests via [JUnit Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JUnit_Request) sampler by compiling your tests into a .jar file and dropping it to "lib/junit" folder of your JMeter installation. Of course you will need to have the necessary Selenium libraries in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath).

If your tests are in Ruby:

1. Download JRuby jar and drop it to lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Install [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
3. Open JMeter and add WebDriver Sampler to your Test Plan
4. Select `ruby` from language dropdown and transfer your existing Ruby code into "script" area (i.e. copy and paste)

   [image: JMeter Ruby WebDriver]

---

Be aware that real browser based performance tests are **very** resource consuming so [consider converting your Selenium tests into "pure" JMeter tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) instead of running them in multithreaded manner.

Comment: I am using cucmber +selenium and java..any idea how can i convert them or any alternate solution for this

Comment: Dmitri, we are yelling into a Hurricane when asking people to be concerned about resources and performance.  Witness people who want to run their load generators to 100% of the resource pool, distorting performance on the generator, or those who don't even integrate monitors to find out what happens when response times go wonky.  This is before you add in people who want to combine functional and performance testing to try to simultaneously solve both or those without training or mentors.   All shortcuts lead to failures in production